# Scala, trait inheritance and chaining, handling specialized method call

Tags: scala, oop, traits

I'm a novice in using advanced OO techniques of scala. I think I have an idea of how trait chaining works. I am still not sure when to inherit another trait in a trait, and when to use a 'self' type. Nor have I ever used dependency injection if its relevant.

EDIT: I've removed analogies and used my actual domain problem since it appeared that I wasn't clear in my question. I hope this makes the question simpler now.

Every Searchable entity can be searched by its name. If an entity is physically located, it can be searched by its location as well. If an entity is an exhibit with summary it can be searched by its summary. To search, we need a map of weights to assign each of these components.

I have a trait Searchable, and traits that implement from it: PhysicallySituated, Exhibit. My code looks like this:

```
trait Searchable{ 
  def getWeight() = {
    val name: String 
    println( "getWeight in Searchable" )
    Map( name -> 20 ) 
  }
}

trait PhysicallySituated extends Searchable{
  val city: String
  val country: String

  override def getWeight() = {
    println( "getWeight in PhysicallySituated" )
    super.getWeight ++ Map( city -> 5, country -> 5 )
  }
}

trait Exhibit extends Searchable{
    val summary: String
    override def getWeight() = {
      println( "Regular getWeight in Exhibit" )
      super.getWeight ++ Map( summary -> 3 )
    }
}

class School extends Searchable with PhysicallySituated with Exhibit
class Book   extends Searchable with Exhibit
```

Now sometimes I want to create a specialized version of `getWeight` of `Exhibit` based on whether this is a 'full search'. So this version would take a parameter `getPrecise: Enumeration` and return a precise weight which also includes description.

```
object Exhibit{
  object Search extends Enumeration{
    val IncludeDescription = Value
    val ExcludeDescription = Value
  }
}

trait Exhibit extends Searchable{
    val summary: String
    override def getWeight() = {
      println( "Regular getWeight in Exhibit" )
      super.getWeight ++ Map( summary -> 3 )
    }

    def getWeight( getPrecise: Exhibit.Search.Value ) = {
      println( "Specialized getWeight in IsGestating" )
      super.getWeight ++  if( getPrecise == Exhibit.Search.IncludeDescription ) Map( summary -> 4 /*4 != 3*/, description -> 2 )  else Map( summary -> 3 )
    }
}

object TraitChaining extends App{
  //Weight depends on order. 

  println( 
    ( new SearchableEntity with Exhibit with PhysicallySituated).
      getWeight( Exhibit.Search.IncludeDescription )  
  )

  println( 
    ( new SearchableEntity with PhysicallySituated with Exhibit).
      getWeight( Exhibit.Search.IncludeDescription )  
  )
}
```

The purpose I want this to serve is that there would be times when I would want to include description in search when I'm doing a full search and I know that the collection of Searchable's has some Exhibits too

`mycollection.filter( _.isInstanceOf[ Exhibit ] ).map( _.asInstanceOf[ Exhibit ].getWeight( getPrecise = Exhibit.Search.IncludeDescription ) ). ++  mycollection.filter( !_.isInstanceOf[ Exhibit ] ).map( _.getWeight ).sum //I know ++ will change order`

Am I thinking of things the right way, or is this pattern itself a no-no from OO point of view?

My reservation is because of two things:

1) Order of traits inheritance matters in this case, major problem. Makes me wonder if my problem itself is amenable to the OOP patterns.
2) What if there were another trait that I derived from, and it had another criterion for 'precise search'? (I could use @millhouse answer as a inspiration to that, pass a Set of flags instead of a single flag, and each trait worries about its own

If this is not the right way, what would be a right way to handle this?  I hope you've understood the intent of the question. Please respond only if you think you're an expert in OO and understand Scala traits very well. I hope an answer that takes up time will actually add value by providing some new information (no offence)

Comment: I would be very wary of using _any_ kind of inheritance to represent a _has-a_ condition, particularly one that (as in this domain) fluctuates over time. No being is ever gestating (i.e. _has-a_ embryo) all the time, so to model it with a trait feels a little odd.

Comment: @millhouse I may have used a somewhat odd example, however, a pregnant bat is always gestating. (I added the meta-question because I really wasn't sure if the example made the problem clearer or more confusing, and it appears it made it more confusing). Specially in my domain. Please see edit.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @millhouse in the comment of your question, your are modelling properties that change over time with `trait`s. Trait resolution is done at compile time, so if you istantiate a `LivingBeing` extending the `IsGestating` trait, that being will be in this state forever.

The use of `trait`s you're trying to use is known as the implementation of the *Decorator design pattern* in Scala. As reported in [this link](https://pavelfatin.com/design-patterns-in-scala/#decorator), in Scala

> the delegation is established statically, at compile time, but that’s usually enough as long as we can arbitrarily combine decorators in place of object creation.

OOP concept are at an higher level of abstraction than the programming languages. Then, each programming language realizes the OOP concept in a different way, but they still adhere to them.

In your case, you need to model some evolutionary mechanism, that allows you to change the state of your `LivingBeing`. For example, you can use the *decorator pattern* not directly applying it to the `LivingBeing`, but applying it to an internal object that models the state that could change its properties over time.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, and while my problem is somewhat different, its good to know about the decorator pattern..

Comment: Absolutely! I think I was too focused on editing the question so as to make it clearer. Upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

OK I'm going to take a shot at this, but seeing as we're using Scala it seems a shame not to do something a little bit more functional and less OO.

It seems to me that (at least based upon your examples), the weight of a `LivingBeing` could be considered to be some **base**, plus **a number of transformations applied to it** depending on whether it has wings, is pregnant, has prey, etc etc.

So why not model it as such:

```
type WeightTransform = Double => Double

case class LivingBeing(transforms:Set[WeightTransform] = Set(),
                       initialWeight:Double = 100D) {

  // the sequence of transforms is immutable, 
  // so getWeight can be a simple val rather than a def:
  val getWeight = transforms.foldLeft(initialWeight) { case (acc, xform) =>
    xform(acc)
  }
}
```

How do we use such a thing? Well, let's define some `WeightTransform` instances:

```
val wingBoost:WeightTransform = _ + 20

val gestatingBoost:WeightTransform = _ + 40
```

Pretty straightforward. Now let's release the bats:

```
val bat = LivingBeing(Set(wingBoost))
// bat.getWeight == 120

val pregnantBat = bat.copy(weightTransforms = Set(wingBoost, gestatingBoost))
// pregnantBat.getWeight == 160

val pregnantBatThatGaveBirth = pregnantBat.copy(weightTransforms = pregnantBat.weightTransforms - gestatingBoost)
// pregnantBatThatGaveBirth.getWeight == 120
```

Some things to note (good or bad, it's up to you):

- We've gone from defining beings at a class level, to an instance-based approach
- Of course you could still write `Builder` or `Factory` objects/functions to construct these things
- Each instance is just a `LivingBeing` - the type hierarchy is totally flat
- A `LivingBeing` is totally immutable, so we make copies when a being changes state (e.g. starts- or ceases-being pregnant)
- Because `LivingBeing` is a case class we get the amazing `copy()` function for free, allowing us to focus on what's changing in these state transitions
- The transformations are a `Set` because:

  - for this simple example, ordering doesn't matter
  - we can use nice Scala collection operators like `-` to remove an element
- A `WeightTransform` is independently testable and has no expectations about being mixed-in with anything else (no `super` headaches)